# unity - xcode build failed with NSUserDefaults.mm file not found message, possibly because com.unity.services.core folder is not in project folder

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, nsuserdefaults

building an XCode project with an .xcodeproj file generated by unity 2021.3.3f1 fails with the message "Build input file cannot be found: 'users/---/ --project name--/Libraries/com.unity.services.core/Runtime/Device/UserIdProviders/NSUserDefinitions.mm' "

When I look in Finder, I notice that the com.unity.services.core does not exist under the Libraries folder.

Some background. I recently moved to trash many Xcode files to free up disk space.  I also did a new remove and Install of XCode, in case I deleted anything important accidentally. Non unity files work fine in XCode.

This might be the first project I used 2021.3.3f1 for.  I previously used 2019.4.14f1 without encountering this problem.

Is there something I should set in the IOS Player settings of Unity BuildSettings to avoid this problem? (or something that would force the com.unity.services.core folder to be generated in the output project)?

I am very inexperienced in Mac and infrastructure so I apologize in advance if I am missing something very basic.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your build folders and build anew, should work.

In Xcode you can do this by going to `Product > Clean Build Folder`, in Unity you just manually delete the whole Build output folder (I hope you created a seperate folder specifically for the Build output and didn't just export to the project directory in that case don't delete your project directory just set a new Build output folder ;).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I especially appreciated the detail of the steps to get to the Clean Build Folder option.

Comment: For the record, the problem was caused by an error on my part.

Comment: For the record, the problem was caused by an error on my part. In Unity, on the build Settings screen, I forgot to switch to the IOS platform.  This is the error that results when you run the xcodeproject file that build settings generates using the PC, Mac & Linux Standalone Platform